# User management API

Tags: c++, python, linux, user-management

I am developing an application suite where users will need to connect to a server and depending on their account type they will be given some services. The server will run Linux. Can you please suggest me some user management API which I can use to develop the server program? By user management I mean user authentication and other related functionalities.
I prefer to work in C++ or python, but any other language should not be a problem. Please note that this application suite is not web based.

Due to security issues, I do not want to give each user a separate account on the linux server.

Thanks,
Akshey

Comment: LDAP maybe could be a solution?

Comment: For authentication purposes use challenge/response algorithms in conjunction with salted hashes to prevent passwords from being transmitted over the network.

Comment: I think more details are needed. What are you trying to achieve, are you developing a web application? Are you trying to let users login via ssh to a server?

Answer (score 0):

http://web.mit.edu/Kerberos/ Not a drop in solution, but not quite sure what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/auth/#topics-auth) is a python framework that provides all these services. It's very modular too, so you only have to use the components that what you want/need.

Its default admin tools provide authentication and authorization. Includes Users, Permissions, Groups, and message queueing.

If you don't want something as high level as a web front end. Twisted provides an authentication/credentials module. (http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/cred.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_Authentication_Modules).

For security, you should only do this over SSL so that the user's password is not sent over the wire in cleartext.